# Error: java.io.IOException: build on Android device failed at task 'processDebugResources'

Tags: cordova, meteor, ubuntu-12.04, phonegap-build, android-build

I am using Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS and my android phone is

**Samsung Galaxy S3 Neo I93001 Android version 4.3** and is connected successfully to the device.

```
~$ adb devices
List of devices attached
* daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
* daemon started successfully *
4e1eb1e1    device
```

When trying to build a sample app in android device getting this error.

> Execution failed for task ':CordovaLib:processDebugResources'.
>
> **java.io.IOException**: Cannot run program
>   "/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/23.0.2/aapt": error=2, No such file or
>   directory
>
> Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
>   Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
>
> BUILD FAILED

```
~/socially1-3$ meteor run android-device --verbose

Getting installed version for platform android in Cordova project
Checking Cordova requirements for platform Android
[[[[[ /socially1-3 ]]]]]

=> Started proxy. 
=> Started MongoDB. 
Local package version is up-to-date: accounts-base@1.2.2
....
Local package version is up-to-date: webapp-hashing@1.0.5

Preparing Cordova project from app bundle 
Processing mobile-config.js 
Copying resources for mobile apps 
Writing new config.xml 
Preparing Cordova project for platform Android

WARNING: You are testing your app on a remote device. For the mobile app to be able to connect to the local server, make sure your device is on
the same network, and that the network configuration allows clients to talk to each other (no client isolation).
Running Cordova app for platform Android with options --device
ANDROID_HOME=/android-sdk-linux
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64

Running: /socially1-3/.meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/android/gradlew cdvBuildDebug -b /socially1-3/.meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/android/build.gradle -PcdvBuildArch=arm -Dorg.gradle.daemon=true
=> Started your app.

=> App running at: http://localhost:3000/ 
:preBuild
:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:preDebugBuild
:checkDebugManifest
:CordovaLib:compileLint
:CordovaLib:copyDebugLint UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:mergeDebugProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:preBuild
:CordovaLib:preDebugBuild
:CordovaLib:checkDebugManifest
:CordovaLib:prepareDebugDependencies
:CordovaLib:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:packageDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:processDebugResources FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':CordovaLib:processDebugResources'.

java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/23.0.2/aapt": error=2, No such file or directory
Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 29.25 secs
Starting app on Android Device \
/socially1-3/.meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:126
throw e;
^
Error code 1 for command: /socially1-3/.meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/android/gradlew with args: cdvBuildDebug,-b,/socially1-3/.meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/android/build.gradle,-PcdvBuildArch=arm,-Dorg.gradle.daemon=true
=> Errors executing Cordova commands:

While running Cordova app for platform Android with options --device:
Error: Command failed: /socially1-3/.meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/android/cordova/run
--device

at ChildProcess.exitCallback (/tools/utils/processes.js:137:23)
at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
at Process.ChildProcess.handle.onexit (childprocess.js:820:12)

ExitWithCode:1
```

I first thought the file '**aapt**' was not available or no permission was there for that file. But the 'aapt' file is available at the specified path and user has read write permission too.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to run a 32bit file on 64bit system. Try

```
>file aapt
```

It should give you the following result

```
aapt: ELF 32-bit LSB shared object ...
```

SDK Manager is actually installing 32 bit file..

Try this fix:

```
(Using software centre or command lines) If your Ubuntu is a 32-bit OS then install libgl1-mesa-dev

In case of 64-bit OS install ia32-libs (Ubuntu 13.04 or earlier), or libgl1-mesa-dev:i386 (Ubuntu 13.10 and above)
```

refer: https://askubuntu.com/questions/318246/complete-installation-guide-for-android-sdk-adt-bundle-on-ubuntu

Comment: indeed the file aapt showed the file was 32 bit and since mine was ubuntu12.04LTS i installed  sudo apt-get install ia32-libs .Now meteor is not generating the above error

Answer (score 0):

According to Android Developer Site,

**Note:**
If you are running a **64-bit version of Ubuntu**, you need to install some 32-bit libraries with the following command:

> sudo apt-get install lib32z1 lib32ncurses5 lib32bz2-1.0 lib32stdc++6

If you are running **64-bit Fedora**, the command is:

> sudo yum install zlib.i686 ncurses-libs.i686 bzip2-libs.i686

Follow the link for installation steps:
https://developer.android.com/studio/install.html